# Write Joint Probability Distribution of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability

[image]

I drew a table labeled $A,B,C$ and I listed all the possible combinations of contracts that can be distributed.

So, we can have $\{(A,B,C):(2,0,0), (0,2,0), (0,0,2), (1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1)\}$

I get: $f(0,0)=\frac16, \space f(0,1)=\frac16, \space f(0,2)=\frac16, \space f(1,0)=\frac16, \space f(1,1)=\frac16,\space f(1,2)=0,\space f(2,0)=\frac16, \space f(2,1)=0,\space f(2,2)=0$

Is this correct?

Comment: I believe f(2,2) is 0 because there are only 2 contracts, so A cannot have 2 contracts if B also gets 2 contracts.  Is this right?

Comment: Right, my table has columns A, B, C. So: Column A: 0,0,2,1,1,0; Column B: 0,2,0,1,0,1; Column C: 2,0,0,0,1,1. (Sorry, don't know if I can draw a table on SE)

Comment: A is for X, B is Y, and C is the other company

Comment: @AWertheim It says the contracts *for the 2 jobs* can be assigned to one or more companies.  Presumably there's just one contract per job, to avoid having the job done twice.

Comment: Ok, so what does that mean?

Comment: We can have {(A,B,C)|(2,0,0), (0,2,0), (0,0,2), (1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1)}

Comment: It means you can assign 2 jobs $N$ and $M$ to the three companies, $A,B,C$ in nine ways, and these can be grouped into equivalence classes where the count of jobs are the same, but the assignments are distinct: $\{(A,B,C):(NM,\underline{\,},\underline{\,})\mid (N,M,\underline{\,}),(M,N,\underline{\,})\mid (N,\underline{\,},M),(M,\underline{\,},N) \mid (\underline{\,},NM,\underline{\,})\mid (\underline{\,},N,M),(\underline{\,},M,N)\mid (\underline{\,},\underline{\,},NM)\}$

Comment: Ah, I see @GrahamKemp, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign probabilities we must count permutations, not combinations.  That is we must consider which company gets which job.

There are nine ways to assign two jobs to three companies, which can be grouped into six equivalence classes where the count of the jobs assigned are identical (but the assigned jobs differ).   There is just *one* way to assign both jobs to any one particular company (with three companies to choose), and there are *two* distinct ways to assign a different job to any two particular companies (with three such pairs).

$\begin{array}{c|ccc} f_{X,Y} & 0 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline 0 & \frac 19 & \frac 29 & \frac 19 \\ 1 & \frac29 & \frac29 & 0 \\ 2 & \frac19 & 0 & 0\end{array}$

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac 1 9 & \text{if } x=y=0 \cup (x+y=2\cap x\neq y) \\ \frac 2 9 & \text{if } x=y=1 \cup (x+y=1 \cap x\neq y) \\ 0 & \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$

Comment: Where is this coming from? Please explain. Thanks

Comment: @Lanfranco You don't just want the number of combinations, you want their probabilities.  So you have to count permutations.